# Second for code only executes for last array item

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

My for code only runs the second line of code for the last array item. How can I fix this? Is using map the correct way of doing this even?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var data = [{test: "1!", test1: "2!", test2: "3!"}];

    console.log(data);

    data.map(function(item) { 
        for (var key in item) 
            
            console.log (key+": "+item[key]);
            
            console.log ("this will only show on the last item - "+key+": "+item[key]);
            
    }).join();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what do you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not putting the code block inside of `{}` of `for`. In that case only the immediate line of code will be considered as part of `for` statement

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var data = [{
    test: "1!",
    test1: "2!",
    test2: "3!"
  }];
  data.map(function(item) {
    for (var key in item) { // changed here , added {}
      console.log(key + ": " + item[key]);
      console.log("this will only show on the last item - " + key + ": " + item[key]);
    }



  }).join();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

add curly braces of for loop, its working

```js
data.map(function(item) { 
        for (let key in item) {
            console.log (key+": "+item[key]);
            console.log ("this will only show on the last item - "+key+": "+item[key]);
        }        
    }).join();
```